# not a pbm, pgm or ppm file. by ocrad

Tags: php

I'm sending a book page photo from browser to PHP. I'm writing the photo to disk using this:

```
$decoded = base64_decode($img);
file_put_contents($output_file, $decoded);
```

However when I run [ocrad](https://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/)/[gocr](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) for the image then `gocr` shows error

> "bad magic bytes, expect 0x50 0x3[1-6] but got 0xff 0xd8"

while `ocrad` says

> "ocrad: bad magic number - not a pbm, pgm or ppm file."

What could be the problem?

Comment: We need to first convert it to pbm, ppm etc format using jpegtopnm then it is working

Answer (score 3):

The bytes `0xff 0xd8` suggest the file is a JPEG.

The error message says "not a pbm, pgm or ppm file" … and a JPEG isn't one of those.